# Reverse generation of RGB PCA image not working

Tags: python, pca

Shakira.jpg

[image]

I am trying to compress the above image but the output that I am getting is an improper image. I think I am doing the PCA steps correctly, but something is going wrong at the final step.

Shakira compressed

[image]

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

img = plt.imread("shakira.jpg")

print(img.shape)
plt.axis('off') 
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

img_reshaped = np.reshape(img, (930, 1860))
print(img_reshaped.shape)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(.95)
pca.fit(img_reshaped)

img_transformed = pca.transform(img_reshaped)
print(img_transformed.shape)

img_inverse = pca.inverse_transform(img_transformed)
print(img_inverse.shape)

plt.imshow(img_inverse)
plt.show()

img_inverse_reshaped = np.reshape(img_inverse, (930,620,3))

print(img_inverse.shape)

plt.axis('off') 
plt.imshow(img_inverse_reshaped)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have messed up the reshape.

1. replace `img_reshaped = np.reshape(img, (930, 1860))`
   with `img_reshaped = np.reshape(img, (img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2]))`
2. replace `img_inverse_reshaped = np.reshape(img_inverse, (930,620,3))`
   with `img_inverse_reshaped = np.reshape(img_inverse, img.shape)`

Once I fixed that, the image started to look more or less reasonable.

Then you have to replace `pca = PCA(.95)` to `pca = PCA(n_components=3)`, and the image will look even pretty =)

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the error in my code as well. If I divide img_inverse_reshaped by 255, the problem gets fixed. Yes, n_components=3 looks pretty :)